# How to compare two row in same table and return the data in response using stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

I have to compare between two rows using two Id's in the same table, and I want to get the columns and their values that are not matching in the stored procedure and I need to return it in JSON format.

```
     |Col1|Col2|Col3|Col4|
Id-1 |ABC |123 |321 |111 |
Id-2 |ABC |333 |321 |123|
```

**Output:**

```
     |col2|col4|
Id-1 |123 |111 |
Id-2 |333 |123 |


JSON OUTPUT Expected

[
   {
      "ColumnName":"COL2",
      "Value1":"123",
      "Value2":"333"
   },
   {
      "ColumnName":"COL4",
      "Value1":"111",
      "Value2":"123"
   }
]
```

I don't have expertise in it however I tried the below SQL code but I need this in a very nice way and that too in a stored procedure and it should be returned in JSON format, please help!

What I have tried, please check the link below with sample example and query.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d05e3/1)

Comment: Please tag the DBMS you're using first of all

Comment: Do you really need a stored procedure?

Comment: @jarlh Yes I do, coz I would be calling the stored proc from .net and there are multiple table comparison that I need to do in the stored proc as if now I'm just asking help with one table

Comment: And which dbms are you using? Not all dbms products support ISO/ANSI SQL stored procedures.

Comment: @jarlh This is quite logical, its a SQL server, have added in the tag as well.

Comment: @Mysterious288, what is the expected JSON output and what is the SQL Server version? JSON support was introduced in SQL Server 2016.

Comment: (1) What is the input for the stored procedure. Is this ST should execute on specific table or is it supposed to be dynamic query. In case of dynamic query we will nee to use sp_executesql ad build the query on the fly. (2) Please provide queries to create the sample table and insert sample data. We need to get your expected result according to the sample data (the expected JSON).

Comment: @Zhorov The SQL Server is 2016 and the expected Json output is [
   {
      "ColumnName":"ABC",
      "Value1":"123",
      "Value2":"288"
   },
   {
      "ColumnName":"XYZ",
      "Value1":"111",
      "Value2":"222"
   }
]

Comment: @RonenAriely The input expected are ID's and since we are doing this on various tables so the column name should not be fixed in the query.

Comment: I don't understand how the input becomes the output. Where does `288` and `222` come from, where is the `address_type` column?

Comment: @Charlieface I think I mixed various examples, I have edited my question now forget about the input, lets focus on the json output and the query that we need over here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unpivot all the columns, then join each row to every other.

You can either pivot everything manually using `CROSS APPLY (VALUES`

```sql
SELECT
  aId = a.id,
  bId = b.id,
  v.columnName,
  v.value1,
  v.value2
FROM @t a
JOIN @t b
    ON a.id < b.id
 -- alternatively
 -- ON a.id = 1 AND b.id = 2
CROSS APPLY (VALUES
   ('col1', CAST(a.col1 AS nvarchar(100)), CAST(b.col1 AS nvarchar(100))),
   ('col2', CAST(a.col2 AS nvarchar(100)), CAST(b.col2 AS nvarchar(100))),
   ('col3', CAST(a.col3 AS nvarchar(100)), CAST(b.col3 AS nvarchar(100))),
   ('col4', CAST(a.col4 AS nvarchar(100)), CAST(b.col4 AS nvarchar(100)))
) v (ColumnName, Value1, Value2)
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT v.Value1 EXCEPT SELECT v.Value2)
FOR JSON PATH;
```

The use of `WHERE EXISTS (SELECT a.Value1 INTERSECT SELECT a.Value2)` means that nulls will get taken into account properly.

---

Or you can use `SELECT t.* FOR JSON` and unpivot using `OPENJSON`

```sql
WITH allValues AS (
    SELECT
      t.id,
      j2.[key],
      j2.value,
      j2.type
    FROM @t t
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT t.*
        FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
    ) j1(json)
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.json) j2
    WHERE j2.[key] <> 'id'
)
SELECT
  aId = a.id,
  bId = b.id,
  columnName = a.[key],
  value1 = a.value,
  value2 = b.value
FROM allValues a
JOIN allValues b ON a.[key] = b.[key]
    AND a.id < b.id
 -- alternatively
 -- AND a.id = 1 AND b.id = 2
WHERE a.type <> b.type
   OR a.value <> b.value
FOR JSON PATH;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=6a15140ffb6fa3d3fae14d57866ad948)

[SQL Fiddle of actual data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7cf41/5)

Comment: I was trying your solution in SQLFiddle and seems like SQL version is an issue http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7cf413/5 would like to know the issues posted as a solution by Zhorov

Comment: Well obviously you need to use SQL Server not MySQL, and you need to put the right column names in http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7cf41/5

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's making a lot of sense, one question though, if all columns are string with a specific size, do we need to CAST??

Comment: You're right we don't. But in many cases you want to do this with idfferent typa or size columns

Comment: Sorry, I accepted both answers, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer:**

A possible solution is a `CROSS JOIN` with an additional `APPLY` operator:

The test data from the fiddle:

```
CREATE TABLE companies ( 
   Id int,
   company_name  VARCHAR(40),
   address_type  VARCHAR(40),
   address    VARCHAR(40)
);
INSERT INTO companies VALUES (1,'Company A','Billing','111 Street');
INSERT INTO companies VALUES (2,'Company A','Shipping','112 Street');
```

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE uspColumnsAsJson 
   @Id1 int,
   @Id2 int
AS
BEGIN
   SELECT a.ColumnName, a.Value1, a.Value2
   FROM (
      SELECT 
         c1.company_name AS company_name1, 
         c1.address_type AS address_type1, 
         c1.address AS address1, 
         c2.company_name AS company_name2, 
         c2.address_type AS address_type2, 
         c2.address AS address2 
      FROM companies c1
      CROSS JOIN companies c2
      WHERE c1.Id = @Id1 AND c2.Id = @Id2
   ) t
   CROSS APPLY (VALUES
      ('company_name', CONVERT(varchar(max), t.company_name1), CONVERT(varchar(max), t.company_name2)),
      ('address_type', CONVERT(varchar(max), t.address_type1), CONVERT(varchar(max), t.address_type2)),
      ('address', CONVERT(varchar(max), t.address1), CONVERT(varchar(max), t.address2))
   ) a (ColumnName, Value1, Value2)
   WHERE a.Value1 <> a.Value2
   FOR JSON AUTO
END

EXEC uspColumnsAsJson 1, 2
```

Result:

```
[
{"ColumnName":"address_type","Value1":"Billing","Value2":"Shipping"},
{"ColumnName":"address","Value1":"111 Street","Value2":"112 Street"}
]
```

**Update:**

If you want to include all columns, you need a dynamic statement based on the system catalog views:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE uspColumnsAsJson 
   @Id1 int,
   @Id2 int
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @stmt nvarchar(max)
   DECLARE @prms nvarchar(max)
   DECLARE @err int

   -- APPLY part
   SELECT @stmt = STRING_AGG(
      CONCAT(
         N'(''',
         col.[name],
         N''', CONVERT(varchar(max), c1.',
         QUOTENAME(col.[name]),
         N'), CONVERT(varchar(max), c2.',
         QUOTENAME(col.[name]),
         N'))'
      ),
      N','
   )   
   FROM sys.columns col
   JOIN sys.tables tab ON col.object_id = tab.object_id
   JOIN sys.schemas sch ON tab.schema_id = sch.schema_id
   WHERE (tab.[name] = 'companies') AND (sch.[name] = 'dbo') AND (col.[name] <> 'Id')
   
   -- Final statement
   SET @stmt = CONCAT(
      N'SELECT a.ColumnName, a.Value1, a.Value2 ',
      N'FROM companies c1 ',
      N'CROSS JOIN companies c2 ',
      N'CROSS APPLY (VALUES ',
      @stmt, 
      N') a (ColumnName, Value1, Value2) ',
      N'WHERE (c1.Id = @Id1) AND (c2.Id = @Id2) AND (a.Value1 <> a.Value2) ',
      N'FOR JSON AUTO '
   )
   
   -- Execution
   SET @prms = N'@Id1 int, @Id2 int'
   EXEC @err = sp_executesql @stmt, @prms, @Id1, @Id2
   RETURN @err
END
```

Comment: Isn't that just a normal `JOIN companies c2 ON c1.Id = 1 AND c2.Id = 2` also you probably want to explicitly cast the column values to the same type

Comment: @Zhorov Thanks for the solution, just curious to know whether we can make the query dynamic so that we don't have to hard code columns.

Comment: @Charlieface, you are right about the cast, but in this specific case all columns are `varchar(40)`, so I missed that part. Thanks, it's an important note.

Comment: @Zhorov Yeah that should be fine as of now since all are strings, I will test and let you know, if all is fine I will mark that as an answer

Comment: @Mysterious288, an update including dynamic statement.

Answer (score 0):

To do your task, we transform data rows to column, select rows where column 2 and column 3 are different, and then convert the result set to JSON format. It is roundabout and complicated to try to handle such a scenario in SQL because you need to perform a self-join, use CROSS APPLY (VALUES … to perform the transposition, and then filter data. The code is extremely long. The usual way is to fetch the original data out of the database and process it in Python or SPL. SPL, the open-source Java package, is easier to be integrated into a Java program and generate simple and concise code. It accomplishes the task with only two lines of code:

|  | A |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | =MSSQL.query("SELECT * FROM t") |
| 2 | =json(A1.pivot@r(id;ColumnName,value).pivot(ColumnName;id,value;"id1":"Value1","id2":"Value2") .select(#2!=#3)) |

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31505937)